# My 3D cursor's xyz is all messed up and doesn't align with the grid, how do I fix this?

Tags: 3d-cursor

for some of the vertices I select it's even upside down sometimes. This wasn't a problem until I pressed some random keys by mistake. Can anyone help?
[image: XYZ doesn't align with the grid.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the rotation in the sidebar, just select the view tab and change the 3D cursor rotation back to 0

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have turned "Local" rotation and orientation on. Go to the top tab that says *Local* and select Global.